# Custom Lightning Record Page Template not showing up in Template Switching Wizard

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce-template, template, page-template

Built a custom lightning record based on the [code here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/08/all-about-custom-lightning-page-templates.html) (the "Making a Record page with collapsing regions" one). It shows up under Custom when i go to build a new lightning record page but when i go to transition an old lightning record page, it is not listed. [An another page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component_tips.htm) (as well as the above link) mentions "The order that you list the regions in a page template is the order that the regions appear in when **admins migrate region content using the template switching wizard** in the Lightning App Builder" so clearly switching existing record pages to a custom template is a functionality that exists. Any idea why my custom template not showing up in the template switching wizard?

Answer (score 1):

It may just take time for it to show up in the template list. I tested with a new custom template a few days ago, and it showed up immediately for new Lightning record pages, but it did *not* show as an option for migrating an existing Lightning record page. Fast-forward to today, and my custom template *does* show as an option under Custom Templates for migrating existing Lightning record pages.

For what it's worth, [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm) specifically states that custom templates are available for new pages.

> Once implemented, your custom template is available in the Lightning App Builder’s **new** page wizard for your page creators to use.

Seems like conflicting (or at least confusing) documentation.